# Verification using Mathematiica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

3. Find the general solution of the system X’ = AX  for the given matrix A. In each case check on the linear independence of solutions by examining the Wronskian. Verify your answer using Mathematica.[given matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcO9a.png)

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SE. Please clarify: What is actually the question here?  Is it: "Can someone do my homework?" This might be done with Mathematica but it is not a Mathematica question. Is it about programming? Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask